# Unevaluated derivatives of known functions after replacement

Tags: evaluation, replacement, vector, hold

I want to make the following replacement work correctly:

```
Array[(2 D[xM[[#1]][t], t] * D[xM[[#2]][t], t]) &, {3, 
   3}] /. {xM -> {Sin[ω t], Cos[ω t], 0}}
```

The array is constructed with a symbolic form given in terms of time derivatives of a vector. For some reason, when I evaluate this expression, I obtain the following:

```
{{2 Derivative[1][Sin[t ω]][t]^2, 
  2 Derivative[1][Cos[t ω]][t] Derivative[1][Sin[t ω]][
    t], 0}, {2 Derivative[1][Cos[t ω]][t] Derivative[1][
    Sin[t ω]][t], 2 Derivative[1][Cos[t ω]][t]^2, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

[image: unevaluated derivatives of known functions]

tried forcing a reevaluation wrapping the result with `Evaluate`, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `Inactivate` and `Activate` functions:

```
Inactivate[
  Array[(2 D[xM[[#1]], t]*D[xM[[#2]], t]) &, {3, 3}], 
   D | Part
] /. {xM -> {Sin[ω t], Cos[ω t], 0}} // Activate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note I removed the `[t]` part from your expressions as that didn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Also effective is

```
Unevaluated[Array[(2 D[xM[[#1]], t]*D[xM[[#2]], t]) &, {3, 3}]] /. 
    {xM -> {Sin[ω t], Cos[ω t], 0}}
(* {{2 ω^2 Cos[t ω]^2, -2 ω^2 Cos[t ω] Sin[t ω], 0}, 
    {-2 ω^2 Cos[t ω] Sin[t ω], 2 ω^2 Sin[t ω]^2, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0}} *)
```